# How do I handle undefined properties from the html in my Angular application before I receive data from my controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-template, angular-template-form

When my Angular component HTML renders. I will get lots of errors that look like this

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'someProperty')

In my HTML page, I have lots of bindings that look like this

```
<h1>{{event.title.toUpperCase()}}</h1>
```

In most components I call a service to fetch data from my controller in the 'ngOnInit()' and I know that one solution to prevent this error before the data comes back from my controller is to make the property nullable like this

```
event?.title
```

but this doesn't seem like a practical solution, especially if I have dozens on the page.

What I have tried -

1. Making them nullable with a '?' but that doesn't seem correct, especially if I always doing it
2. Setting the object type being returning from the controller to a 'any' (ex. event: any), but in some cases it still shows an error

QUESTION - What's the best solution to handle this so I don't keep getting these errors until my page data loads?

Should I have some conditional like *ngIf="event" and hide the page until the data is received and show some loading indicator while waiting? Or is some way to jsut prevent these error from showing in the console?

EDIT - here is the code I use to fetch data from the controller and set it to 'event'

```js
// component
event: any;

// ngOnInit()
this.eventService.getEvent(this.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(response => {
  this.event = response;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

// service
getEvent(id: number): Observable <any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'events/' + id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Defining a boolean variable and checking if data has been loaded is the best approach:

```
// component
event: any;
loaded: boolean;


// ngOnInit()
this.eventService.getEvent(this.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(response => {
  this.event = response;
  this.loaded = true;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

In your HTML page, place your HTML tags inside a section or a div tag as follows:

```
<section *ngIf="loaded">

// your HTML tags here

</section>
```

In this way you do not keep getting undefined errors and bindings will happen only when data is really loaded. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your affected html into something like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="event">
...
</ng-container>
```

When reading your description i'd also suggest to use the observable that is your http-call as an async-binding in your template instead of mapping it to a concrete object "event".

To provide you some more information on that however more code is required from your side.
[EDIT]
Your JS:

```
// class member
event$: Observable<any> = of(undefined);

// whereever
this.event$ = this.eventService.getEvent(this.id).pipe(take(1),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    //or return something else
    return throwError(error);
  }));
```

Binding in HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(event$ | async) as event">
...
</ng-container>
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: Hi Malte. Thanks for commenting. YOu said "i'd also suggest to use the observable that is your http-call as an async-binding in your template" can you provide some example of this so I can understand what you're saying? I can provide more code if requested?

Comment: As posted i'd require you to provide the code snippet where you fetch data and set the event-variable. Based on that i could give you some advice for sure.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Hi Malte. Thanks for editing your answer. Quesiton - would a catchError in your example be necessary if I already have an error interceptor that checks for any HttpRequest errors?

Comment: Question - is there any advantage/benefit for mapping with an async binding vs a concrete object?

Comment: No, the catchError is simply there because i wanted to keep it as close at the original post as possible.

Advantages by binding with async-pipe:
 - no need to destroy subscriptions and with it no memory-leaks by forgetting it for angular handles them by itself
 - no chance to mutate stuff that should not be mutated
 - code that is less verbose and more self explanatory

To be honest when using cold observables like http-calls it is not too important, but for consistency i would always recommend using the approach of async template binding.

Comment: I thought using pipe(take(1)) unsubscribed it?

Comment: Yes, you unsubsribe it, right.
As i said using subscriptions requires you to think about unsubscribing, most of the time resulting in more code, and if you forget it chances are qou will run into problems by time.
This might not be the case with cold observables like your http-call, but, as also posted above, it's good practice, be it to keep your codebase consistent alone.